# IllegalStateException when trying to run spark streaming with twitter

Tags: spark-streaming

I am new to spark and scala.  I am trying to run an example given in google.  I am encounting following exception when running this program.

Exception is:

```
17/05/25 11:13:42 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Error starting Twitter stream - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing.
```

Code that I am executing is as follows:

PrintTweets.scala

```
package example

    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import Utilities._

object PrintTweets {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        // Configure Twitter credentials using twitter.txt
        setupTwitter()
        val appName = "TwitterData"    
        val conf = new SparkConf()    
        conf.setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[3]")    

        val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))        
        //val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "PrintTweets", Seconds(10))
        setupLogging()
        // Create a DStream from Twitter using our streaming context
        val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
        // Now extract the text of each status update into RDD's using map()
        val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
        statuses.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }  
}

Utilities.scala

package example

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher

object Utilities {
    /** Makes sure only ERROR messages get logged to avoid log spam. */
  def setupLogging() = {
      import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}   
      val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
      rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)   
  }

  /** Configures Twitter service credentials using twiter.txt in the main workspace directory */
    def setupTwitter() = {
        import scala.io.Source

        for (line <- Source.fromFile("../twitter.txt").getLines) {
            val fields = line.split(" ")
            if (fields.length == 2) {
                System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + fields(0), fields(1))
      }
    }
  }

  /** Retrieves a regex Pattern for parsing Apache access logs. */
  def apacheLogPattern():Pattern = {
    val ddd = "\\d{1,3}"                      
    val ip = s"($ddd\\.$ddd\\.$ddd\\.$ddd)?"  
    val client = "(\\S+)"                     
    val user = "(\\S+)"
    val dateTime = "(\\[.+?\\])"              
    val request = "\"(.*?)\""                 
    val status = "(\\d{3})"
    val bytes = "(\\S+)"                     
    val referer = "\"(.*?)\""
    val agent = "\"(.*?)\""
    val regex = s"$ip $client $user $dateTime $request $status $bytes $referer $agent"
    Pattern.compile(regex)    
  }
}
```

When I check using print statments I find the exception is happening at line 
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

I am giving credentials in twitter.txt file which is read properly by program.  When I don't place twitter.txt in appropriate directory it shows explicit error, It shows explicit error unauthorized access when I give blank keys for customer key and secret etc in twitter.txt

If you need more details about error related information or versions of software let me know.

Thanks,
Madhu.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the issue with your code. I believe its your problem.
You might have not configured twitter.txt properly. Your twitter.txt file should be like this ->

```
consumerKey your_consumerKey
consumerSecret your_consumerSecret
accessToken your_accessToken
accessTokenSecret your_accessTokenSecret
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.  Its my mistake, twitter.txt is the problem.  After modifying as per your suggestion, it works.

Comment: Madhu, can you select this as an answer so that it would other fellows as well.

Answer (score 0):

After changing twitter.txt file syntax to following , single space between key and value it worked

consumerKey your_consumerKey
consumerSecret your_consumerSecret
accessToken your_accessToken
accessTokenSecret your_accessTokenSecret